# Does a function from $\mathbb R^2$ to $\mathbb R$ which sums to 0 on the corners of any unit square have to vanish everywhere?

Tags: discrete-geometry, euclidean-geometry, recreational-mathematics, puzzle

> **Does a function from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$ which sums to 0 on the corners of any unit square have to vanish everywhere?**

I think the answer is yes but I am not sure how to prove it.

If we allow any square of any size the answer is yes - an old Putnam problem. You obtain the same result if you restrict to squares of any size parallel to the axes. However, if you take only unit squares parallel to the axes the answer is no.

Note that an obvious idea for a counterexample is to try to colour the plane with 2 colours so that any two points a unit distance apart have different colours. However this is trivial to disprove.

Comment: The title and the body are asking in the opposite senses, so "yes" could mean "yes, there is a nonzero function ..." or "yes, a function ... has to vanish".

Comment: @JukkaKohonen I have edited the title to fix this mismatch.

Comment: Where might one find a proof of the result concerning squares of any size parallel to the axes?

Comment: @Gro-Tsen I might have messed up this calculation, but I think that if you let $S$ be the set of integer points $(i,j)$ with $1\le i\le 7$ and $1\le j \le 7$, and write down the $1^2 + 2^2 + \cdots + 6^2$ linear equations implied by the condition, then you get a matrix of full rank.

Comment: @Gro-Tsen You can actually prove this for $\mathbb{Z}^2$. Denote the vertex values in any 2x2 square by
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b & c\\
d & e & f\\
g &h & i
\end{bmatrix}
Using the 1x1 square sums we add $a+b+d+e=0$ to $e+f+h+i=0$ and subtract $d+e+g+h=0$ and $b+c+e+f=0$ giving $a+i=g+c$. 

The 2x2 corner square sum is $a+c+i+g=0$ so $a+i=g+c=0$. Hence any 2x2 square has corner values of the form 

\begin{bmatrix}
a & -g\\
g & -a
\end{bmatrix}

This implies any 4x4 square has corner values all equal:

\begin{bmatrix}
a & a\\
a & a
\end{bmatrix}

implying $a=0$.

Comment: @IvanMeir Ah, we don't need a matrix of full rank because we just need to prove that *some* vertex value must be zero. But I guess going up to a 6x6 square has the advantage that one just needs to check the matrix has full rank, and one doesn't need to do any solving of the equations.

Comment: @TimothyChow Yes that's the case. The vertex value must be in a fixed position such as the centre or top left corner. In the 4x4 case you can vastly simplify by applying all the square symmetries about the centre and adding the resultant grids. This gives another set of grid values with the zero sum properties:

\begin{bmatrix}
0 & a & b & a & 0\\
a & 0 & c & 0 & a\\
b & c & d & c & b\\
a & 0 & c & 0 & a\\
0 & a & b & a & 0\\
\end{bmatrix}

It is then immediate that $a=b=c=d=0$.

Comment: Since the centre point is invariant under the symmetries this means that the original centre value must have been 0.

Comment: The 5x5 case is the first one which has a unique solution with all zero values. The 4x4 case solves to \begin{bmatrix}
0 & a & 0 & -a & 0\\
0 &-a & 0 & a & 0\\
0 & a & 0 & -a & 0\\
0 &-a & 0 & a & 0\\
0 & a & 0 & -a & 0\\
\end{bmatrix} where $a$ is an arbitrary value.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The answer is yes, I learned this from the paper that appeared on arXiv literally yesterday https://arxiv.org/abs/2403.01279, they quote

R. Katz, M. Krebs and A. Shaheen, [Zero sums on unit square vertex
sets and plane colorings](https://doi.org/10.4169/amer.math.monthly.121.07.610), *Amer. Math. Monthly* **121** (2014), no. 7, 610–618.

for this exact result about the unit square.